# securing jolokia actuator endpoint not working when accessing through hawt.io

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, hawtio

I've got hawtio 2.1.0 installed connecting to the jolokia endpoint exposed by a spring boot 2.0.5 app.

My app yaml contains

```
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "jolokia"
    jmx:
      exposure:
        exclude: "*"
  endpoint:
    jolokia:
      enabled: true
      config:
        debug: true
```

In addition I have a filter

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(ShutdownEndpoint.class))
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class, InfoEndpoint.class))
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
```

When I access the jolokia actuator endpoint in my browser it correctly asks me for my credentials.
So using this method the endpoints are secured.

When I connect to the jolokia endpoint through the hawt.io web app I don't need to provide any credentials. It makes no differnence if hawt.io is running on a remote or on the local maschine the spring boot app is running on. Hawt.io is able to get all the MBean infos via jolokia.

How can that be?
Hawt.io somehow circumvents the securing of the jolokia actuator endpoint.

Any ideas why this is or how I can secure the jolokia actuator endpoint so that even hawt.io prompts for the credentials?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers

Oliver

Comment: As far as I know, hawt.io doesn't use the Actuator's Jolokia endpoint. I believe it uses a Java agent. There's some more information in the documentation: http://hawt.io/docs/faq/#how-do-i-connect-to-my-remote-jvm. Exactly how you secure things will depend on how Hawt.io has established its connection with the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't use the jolokia jvm agent but the jolokia actuator endpoint of spring boot:

Comment: Are you sure that hawt.io is using the Actuator endpoint? How have you configured it to do so?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't use the jolokia jvm agent but the jolokia actuator endpoint of spring boot: ```Registered '/actuator/jolokia' to jolokia-actuator-endpoint```.  Within hawtio I added a remote connection to 
http://localhost:8081/actuator/jolokia which is the spring boot actuator endpoint. Question still is why doesn't hawtio prompt me for the credentials to access the jolokia endpoint?

Comment: I don't start the spring boot app using ```java -javaagent:agent.jar ...```.

Comment: I don't think that matters. As described in the documentation that I linked to above, hawt.io can dynamically add the agent to a JVM. I suspect that's what's happening here.

Comment: I get the same behaviour when hawt.io is installed on a collegue's machine accessing my spring boot app on my machine via http. hawtio would be a huge threat if it could remotely add the jolokia agent to any VM running in the network.

Comment: What happens if removing `management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude = *`?  This should mean not exposing anything from JMX/Jolokia.

Comment: It would also be a huge threat if it could bypass HTTP security. Perhaps you can update your question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) so that others can see exactly what you are seeing?